# Python list: Extract integers from list of strings

Tags: python, list, extract

I have a list with the following values, which in fact are strings inside the list:

```
mylist = ['4, 1, 2', '1, 2', '120, 13', '223, 10']
```

How can I extract each value and create a new list with every value inside the list above?

I need a result like:

```
mylist = [4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 120, 13, 223, 10]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `[int(i) for s in ["1,2","3","4,5"] for i in s.split(",")]` both looks weirder and avoids join-hack at the same time.

Comment: @tevemadar so you are suggesting he make the code more complex, look worse and take longer rather than to use a function that perfectly fits the need?

Comment: @EliHarold don't bet hastly about the performance, `join()` makes a copy of the strings, and then `split()` makes another, at least in CPython. That may end up being expensive. Anyway, it's simply a generic pattern for flattening, like `[i for s in [[1,2],[3],[4,5]] for i in s]` looks the same and does the same, just for a list of lists instead of a list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension like so:

```
mylist = ['4, 1, 2', '1, 2', '120, 13', '223, 10']
output = [int(c) for c in ",".join(mylist).split(",")]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 120, 13, 223, 10]
```

This makes a single string of the values and the separates all of the values into individual strings. It then can turn them into ints with `int()` and add it to a new `list`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd offer a solution that is verbose but may be easier to understand

```py
mylist = ['4, 1, 2', '1, 2', '120, 13', '223, 10', '1', '']

separtedList = []
for element in mylist:
    separtedList+=element.split(',')

integerList = []
for element in separtedList:
    try:
        integerList.append(int(element))
    except ValueError:
        pass # our string seems not not be an integer, do nothing

mylist = integerList
print(mylist)
```